# Is there a limit to how long a user query can be for an Action on Google?

Tags: actions-on-google

For example, if someone wanted to make a journal skill it might ask "What would you like to add for your journal today?"

Some users may have a response that would be several sentences long or maybe even a few minutes. Is there any hard limit to how long a user's response/query to an action can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still looking for this answer, after some digging I found it nested deep in the Google Cloud Docs as I was looking to build something similar.

Maximum detect intent text input length is 256 characters.

There are also some handy limits so check it out. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no specific limit on how long the user can speak, the Assistant does have some heuristics to determine when they are "done" talking. These heuristics seem to be better tuned for short replies, rather than long dictation, so it may choose even a slight pause to be the "break".

There is currently no way to indicate the user can talk for a longer duration, or specify when they have finished their response. There are a few tricks you can work with (rapidly respond so they can continue talking, for example), but the system is not currently well suited for long input.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks! Do you know if there is a limit for when users type text into Google Assistant?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I got what you are trying to build. Do you mean a "text to speech" response or an audio response?

A text-to-speech response has the following limit. [AoG Site](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses)

> 640 character limit per chat bubble. Strings longer than the limit are
>   truncated at the first word break (or whitespace) before 640
>   characters.

A media response, instead, has not defined limit:

> Media responses let your Actions play audio content with a playback duration longer than the 120-second limit of SSML. The primary component of a media response is the single-track card. The card allows the user to perform these operations [...]

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear what I meant was, when as user talks to a skill/action, is there a limit to how long their message to the action can be? You cited what the limit of how long an action's response can be, which is helpful, but i'm looking for how long a user's message to an action can be.